# Error on datepicker directive

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, directive

I am coding my app using dreamweaver and it keeps prompting that I have an error on this specific line. I really wonder what's the problem with my code.

```
.directive('datepicker', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //using $parse instead of scope[attrs.datepicker] for cases
            //where attrs.datepicker is 'foo.bar.lol'
            parsed = $parse(attrs.datepicker);
            $(element).datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        parsed.assign(scope, dateText);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont know either, the dreamweaver just notifies that there is a syntax error on the line that contains ".directive('datepicker', ['$parse', function($parse) { "  but I don't know what is it @WK

Comment: You are missing closing `])`

Comment: Maybe does the error regard to a global variable `parsed`? In `"strict mode"` setting a global variable in this way is forbidden.

Comment: People still use Dreamweaver ?

Comment: Yeah haha @LoremIpsum, sometimes I use dreamweaver. I just graduated for my bachelors degree and we are using dreamweaver way back then.haha :)